# How do I check if collection exist in firestore (not document) in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hoi, I would like to check, using React javascript, if a collection in the Firestore already exists, no matter if it's empty or not. I tried:

```
if (collection(db, ref)) // is always true somehow
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to try to fetch from the collection and see if anything is returned:

```
const snap = await query(collection(db, ref), limit(1));
if (snap.empty) {
  // no docs in collection
}
```

Comment: I would like to check for collections, not docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function available in the SDK that can help you can check if a particular collection exists. A collection will start to exist only if it contains at least one document. If a collection doesn't contain any documents, then that collection doesn't exist at all. So that being said, it makes sense to check whether a collection contains or not documents. In code, it should look as simple as:

```
const snapshot = await query(collection(db, yourRef), limit(1));
if (snapshot.empty) {
  //The collection doesn't exist.
}
```

One thing to mention is that I have used a call to `limit(1)` because if the collection contains documents, then we limit the results so we can pay **only** one document read. However, if the collection doesn't exist, there is still one document read that has to be paid. So if the above query yields no resul## Heading ##t, according to the official documentation regarding [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing), it said that:

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of **one document read** for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

Comment: Hey flying_kaktus. Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the collection out of the database and check if it has more than 0 documents. Even, if the collection doesn't exist, it will return 0.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("YOUR COLLECTION NAME").get().then((res) =>{
     if(res.size==0){
          //Collection does not exist
     }else{
          //Collection does exist
     }
```

Comment: The OP is using the modern Firebase SDK but this answer uses the legacy SDK syntax. The other answers here also include the optimizations of using `limit(1)` and `.empty`. I recommend highlighting/adjusting these points in your answer.